# ADO.NET SqlClient connection string - Data Source syntax

Tags: ado.net, connection-string, sqlclient

Is there any official write-up what forms can Data Source field take in sql server connection string? I'm aware of following forms:

```
SERVER
SERVER\Instance
tcp:SERVER,port
nb:SERVER
nb:SERVER\Instance
```

are there more forms?

**EDIT**: The essence of this exercise is not to construct a connection string. I am trying to parse existing connection string, and I want to know all the forms it could take. I appreciate everybody who pointed me to [www.connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com), and this site is useful enough, but it clearly does not have all the information. For example, it will not specify that it is possible to use construct like "Data Source=tcp:SERVER,10000" to specify that TCP must be used for this datasource on port 10000.

Comment: check www.connectionstrings.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check this website for all connection string questions:  http://www.connectionstrings.com

Answer (score 0):

This website has more than you could possibly ever want to know about connection strings for SQL Server and many other databases:

[Connection strings for SQL Server 2005](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2005)